# LibreOffice Calc: scroll one row per mouse wheel click

Tags: ubuntu, scrolling, libreoffice-calc

When I use the mouse wheel to scroll in LibreOffice Calc, it scrolls three rows with each mouse wheel click. Sometimes I need to paste large chunks of text into one cell. This cell then become very high, and scrolling one click results in rows disappearing off screen too quick.

There is space enough for this high row, but it disappears and then I always question whether I've moved down too much or not. Moving up it moves three high rows up, which is even more annoying. You have no control and that is annoying.

**Is it possible to set this to one row? How can I do that?**

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm using Ubuntu Linux, and I see no such option.

Comment: Then you need to check your Ubuntu mouse settings. It is not a LibreOffice setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I scroll one row per mouse wheel click?

This is a general mouse setting not a LibreOffice setting, so changing it will affect all applications.

To change the number of rows scrolled (assuming you are using Windows):

1. Click "Start" > "Control Panel > "Mouse".
2. Select the "Wheel" tab.
3. Change "The following number of lines at a time" to `1`.
4. Click "OK"

Note:

- Some applications have mouse settings which override this, for example Firefox has "Use Smooth Scrolling".

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to how to scroll one line per wheel click, but it is a solution to the actual problem, which is kind of an XY problem I realise now.

You can select the complete sheet, then [**adjust the height of all rows**](https://askubuntu.com/a/138188/55365) by dragging the top border of one row to something acceptable. This means all rows get the same height, whether it's used or not. Big chunks of text won't make that row higher.

Now you can scroll normally again.