# How to scroll faster (vertically) in LibreOffice Calc using mouse wheel (trackball wheel)?

Tags: performance, mouse, libreoffice, scrolling, usability

I have a large LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet with over 5000 rows.

I regularly import fresh data into the spreadsheet using a process that I automated.  I cannot control the original data, or how it is organized.

I often need to scroll (vertically) through the spreadsheet to review all the data.  To improve my performance of completing this task, I've set up a bunch of conditional styles.  Thus, I can visually notice different colors, font sizes, font weights, cell borders, etc. as I scroll through the spreadsheet.

To further improve the speed at which I can perform this task, I would like to increase the speed at which LibreOffice scrolls (vertically) when using the pointing device (trackball, mouse, etc.).

Ideally, I would like the scroll rate to increase as I roll the trackball scroll wheel faster.  This is commonly called "acceleration".

What I don't want to do is statically increase the *number* of rows scrolled by each wheel "click" (as proposed in the accepted answer to [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1127569/libreoffice-calc-scroll-one-row-per-mouse-wheel-click)).  I want to keep that number to a minimum so I easily scroll just a few rows.

I have searched through LibreOffice, including it's advanced settings, and have not yet found a solution.

How can I accomplish this goal?

Answers for all operating systems are appreciated.  Answers for OpenOffice.org Calc are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on Mac with a custom mouse driver - I know of no other way.

[SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) has always been my go-to. You can customise acceleration per app, per pointing device.
[USB Overdrive](https://www.usboverdrive.com) is another candidate, but not one I'm familiar with.

OP didn't ask for a product rec, but on Mac there is no 1st party way to do this.
Logitech's Logi Options can do this too, not as nicely & only if you have a qualifying Logi mouse. Upside: it's free.

Comment: Thank you.  Upvoted.  For which of Logitech's pointing devices is "Logi Options" available.  Years ago, I would install Logitech's special pointing device software, but as operating systems advanced, I eventually found it to be unneeded.  It might be time to take another look.  (BTW, I'm looking for Linux and Windows solutions too.)

Comment: Logitech's CP works for [afaik] most modern-ish Logi mice. There's a Windows version too, but idk if it has the exact same parameters. I currently use an MX2 on Mac, which very annoyingly hides some of the transmitted button info in some non-standard way I don't have the chops to fully comprehend, but it makes SteerMouse not as useful as it used to be on a less "smart" mouse & consequently I've lost some of the really 'tweaky' high-end functionality SM could give me & have to use Logi Opt instead..